# Группировка и суммирование по не календарному году

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица с ежемесячными списаниями. Структура данных простая, но  обычно не начинают пользоваться услугами 1 января:

```
+------+------------------+------------+
| user | monthly_accruals |    date    |
+------+------------------+------------+
| 1    |               50 | 2012-05-06 |
+------+------------------+------------+
| 1    |               70 | 2012-06-12 |
+------+------------------+------------+
...
+------+------------------+------------+
| 1    |              100 | 2013-05-11 | 
+------+------------------+------------+
| 2    |               50 | 2012-09-15 | 
+------+------------------+------------+
| 2    |               70 | 2012-10-09 | 
+------+------------------+------------+
```

Нужно посчитать, сколько каждый клиент заплатил за каждый свой год пользования услугой, и желательно вывести начало и номер года. Примерно так:

```
+------+-------+------------+------+
| user | summa |  date_beg  | year |
+------+-------+------------+------+
| 1    |   570 | 2012-05-06 |    1 |
+------+-------+------------+------+
| 1    |   100 | 2013-05-11 |    2 |
+------+-------+------------+------+
| 2    |   120 | 2012-09-15 |    1 |
+------+-------+------------+------+
```

В MSSQL я бы, возможно, смог бы сделать это с помощью `OVER`, но как это сделать на MySQL?

Comment: а если есть запись для `user=1 and date='2013-05-05'`, то она должна попасть в первую или во вторую строку результата?

Comment: Платежи помесячно, поэтому от месяца, когда совершен первый платеж плюс одиннадцать следующих месяцев - это первый год.
С 13 по 24 месяца включительно - второй год.
И т.д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

чтобы упростить *select*, я добавил отдельный *view*, но при необходимости его можно интегрировать внутрь *select*-а.

если я правильно понял комментарий, то года считаются от *самого первого* платежа.

при составлении самой сложной конструкции воспользовался вот [этим ответом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7749665/4827341).

получилось примерно так:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e305/5)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t (u int, m int, d date);

insert into t values
   (1, 50, '2012-05-06')
  ,(1, 70, '2012-06-12')
  ,(1, 100, '2013-05-11')
  ,(2, 50, '2012-09-15')
  ,(2, 70, '2012-10-09')
;

create view v as
select u
  , min(date_sub(d, interval dayofmonth(d) - 1 day)) as s
from t
group by u;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select u, date_format(s, '%Y-%m-%d') as d
from v
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e305/5/0)**:

```
| u |          d |
|---|------------|
| 1 | 2012-05-01 |
| 2 | 2012-09-01 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select
    t.u as user
  , sum(t.m) as summa
  , date_format(min(t.d), '%Y-%m-%d') as date_beg
  , year(t.d) -
    year(v.s) -
    (
      date_format(t.d, '%m%d') <
      date_format(v.s, '%m%d')
    ) + 1
  as year
from t
join v
 on v.u = t.u
group by user, year
order by user, year
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e305/5/1)**:

```
| u | summa |   date_beg | year |
|---|-------|------------|------|
| 1 |   120 | 2012-05-06 |    1 |
| 1 |   100 | 2013-05-11 |    2 |
| 2 |   120 | 2012-09-15 |    1 |
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это решение помогло.